# MySQL if/conditional query?

Tags: mysql, select, join, subquery

Lets say I have one membership table with the following columns:

```
id, first, last, email, type, expires, parentid
```

Where type can be either "parent" or "child"

If I query an id that is a child, how do I return the name of the child info AND expiration/name of the parent?

Basically like this:

```
select 
  first, 
  last, 
  email, 
  if (type = "child"
      select 
      expires, 
      first as parent_first, 
      last as parent_last 
    from members 
    where id = parentid) 
  else ( expires ) 
  from members where id = 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't approach it from the perspective of dynamically constructing the SQL based on the `type = 'child'`. Instead, SQL operates on related sets so the solution is really to `LEFT JOIN` the table against itself so that the parent is always returned (though sometimes may be null).

While it is possible to use a `CASE` with a subselect to alternately return the parent or child `expires` alone, since you also want the parent's name columns the solution is to *always* return them even though they may be `NULL`.

```
SELECT
  c.first AS first,
  c.last AS last,
  c.email AS email,
  c.expires AS expires,
  /* parent fields will be NULL if child parentid is NULL */
  p.first AS parent_first,
  p.last AS parent_last,
  p.expires AS parent_expires
FROM
  members c
  /* join against the same table matching 
     parentid of the child to id of the parent */
  LEFT JOIN members p ON c.parentid = p.id
WHERE 
  c.id = 100
```

A `LEFT JOIN` is used - therefore if the child has no value for `parentid`, the parent columns will return NULL.  If you only want one value for `expires` returned, you might use `COALESCE()` to prefer the parent's and return the child's if the parent's is null:

```
SELECT
  ...
  COALESCE(p.expires, c.expires) AS expires,
```

Or using `CASE` and checking the child's `type` (though `COALESCE()` is nicer):

```
SELECT
  ...
  CASE WHEN c.type = 'child' THEN p.expires ELSE c.expires END AS expires
```

Comment: Interesting. Coming from the coding side of things, getting the value of something that MIGHT not be set can be asking for trouble (like querying a non-existent column)....so that definitely would explain why I never looked in that direction. But this would then require me to "if !expires then parent_expires" on the presentation side which I was hoping to avoid by always having an "expires". Thanks for the response and the explanation! :)

Comment: @Ahhk No, you don't need to do "if !expires then parent_expires" on the presentation side. That's what the `COALESCE()` above handles for you. It returns the parent expires if it is present, otherwise the child expires (which assumes no parent)

Comment: Ah! It's all starting to make sense now :) Thanks again.